# OpenCV + Python - get average RGB around point

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to opencv.
My Idea is: I have a picture, and defined 4 points (pixels?) e.g. 0x0,0x100,100x0,100x00
What would be best approach to probe each of those BUT, creating square around them.
so e.g. for 0x0 (well not the best example as it can't go around), so let's say 50x50 point and create some kind of mask around that pixel let's say 10x10 pixels square width and height, and then get average RGB of that square, and then do it for all points.

So far I can only probe single points for RGB, but don't have an idea how to approach masking.
I have a feeling like openCV could have some easy solution for that, but all I am finding is super overcomplicated (imho) code that I don't really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an irregular region, then make a mask for it. You can compute the mean of region corresponding to the mask in Python/OpenCV as follows:

Input:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

```
import cv2

# load image 
img = cv2.imread('zelda1.jpg')

# load mask as grayscale
mask = cv2.imread('zelda1_mask.png', 0)

# get mean of pixels corresponding to mask
mean = cv2.mean(img, mask=mask)

# print mean of each channel including alpha; alpha=0 is opaque
print(mean)

# mask region on input
region = img.copy()
img_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('zelda1_region2.jpg', img_masked)

# Display input
cv2.imshow('input', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('input masked', img_masked)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Region of image where mean is computed:

[image]

Mean:

```
(50.23702664796634, 32.84151472650771, 198.3702664796634, 0.0)
```

Comment: this is great, thank you very much. That will give me good starting point to my project

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV using Numpy slicing to get a square region about any give point.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2

# load image 
img = cv2.imread('zelda1.jpg')

# Define point
x = 90
y = 200

# Define region size
rr = 10

# crop image +-20 pixels
crop = img[y-rr:y+rr, x-rr:x+rr]

# compute mean
mean = cv2.mean(crop)

# print mean of each channel including alpha; alpha=0 is opaque
print(mean)

# draw region on input
region = img.copy()
cv2.rectangle(region, (x-rr,y-rr), (x+rr,y+rr), (255,255,255), 1)

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('zelda1_region.jpg', region)

# Display input
cv2.imshow('input', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Region:

[image]

Mean of region for each channel:

(53.6175, 35.9, 205.2375, 0.0)

Comment: This is what I needed. However I came to the new problem, when crop or testing region won't be square or rectangle so it won't have 90 degrees angles how would I "crop" that ?